# Running fsck in each boot and apply fixes without input

Tags: ubuntu

I have seen answers and know how to configure Ubuntu to run fsck in each boot:

```
tune2fs -c 1 /dev/xxx
```

This works and I verified that a check was performed after a reboot. But I am unable to find documentation confirmation that this is a real and full check, and not just a fast check.

And if that any issues were found it would be automatically fixed like you run fsck with -y

I was unable to find any logs detailing the checks after rebooting either. I can only find time of last check with tune2fs -l but I would like to have more logs.

Those servers run with heavy read/writes 24 hours and almost never reboot. So I want to make sure that after a reboot the filesystem will be truly checked for any error, and any will be automatically fixed if possible and where the log of issues are

Comment: Why would you want to run `fsck` at each boot? It's unnecessary in many modern cases. If you don't trust the filesystem to get it right in normal (heavy) use, why should you trust `fsck` any better?

Comment: Just want to make sure that hardware issues will be caught early. Since rebooting is very infrequent anyway

Comment: You are not going to find hardware issues by running `fsck` on boot. You should periodically check SMART data instead.

Comment: In fact, if there are hardware issues, running `fsck` is _more_ likely, not less likely, to destroy your filesystem

Comment: So what is the purpose of fsck ? Also I have backups, the data is not important, only that the hardware is not failing / slowing down.

Comment: `fsck` is used with some filesystems to fix up errors resulting from an unclean unmount. Journaling filesystems rarely require an explicit `fsck`, if ever. Some filesystems don't even have the `fsck` tool. If you want to check hardware, use SMART monitoring with something like `smartmon`